# Determine the conditions on $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $\mathsf{M}$ is positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

**Problem statement:**

Given the matrix

$\mathsf{M} = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    a & b & c & b & a \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$,

> what are the conditions on $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $\mathsf{M}$ is positive semidefinite?

**Solution attempt:**

The eigenvalues of $\mathsf{M}$ are given by

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ c \end{bmatrix}$.

> Does this mean that $c \geq 0$ for $\mathsf{M}$ to be positive semidefinite, independent of the values of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Positive semidefinite is not the same thing as saying that a matrix has positive eigenvalues

Comment: For $M$ to be psd, all principal minors of $M$ have to be non-negative.

Comment: @StubbornAtom that only applies if $M$ is symmetric

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh sure.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom are positive eigenvalues indicative of a positive semidefinite matrix if the matrix is symmetric?

Comment: @daneel non-negative eigenvalues are indicative of a positive semidefinite matrix if the matrix is symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M$ is PSD if and only if the symmetric matrix $M + M^T$ has non-negative eigenvalues.  In this case, we find that $M$ is PSD if and only if $c \geq 0$ and $a = b = 0$.

Note in particular that $M + M^T$ has the principal submatrices
$$
\pmatrix{0&a\\a&2c}, \quad \pmatrix{0&b\\b&2c}
$$
The first matrix is indefinite whenever $a \neq 0$, and the second is indefinite whenever $b \neq 0$.

Comment: Is your first sentence a general statement?

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes

Comment: @Omnomnomnom is there a good reference you could direct me to that contains the general statement in your first sentence?

Comment: @daneel it's fairly standard but I can't think of one off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom no worries, thanks!